# PhoneGap download image to a specific folder

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am building PhoneGap based application for iOS platform.
I want to download few image files to a specific directory.

I want to store downloaded images in folder `www/my_img/`

So that in my app I can further use this image as:

```
<img src="my_img/downloaded.jpg" width="100px" height="100px">
```

I am using PhoneGap plugin for downloading images:

```
var url = 'http://myServer.com/img.jpg';
var filePath = 'www/my_img/';
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(url);

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
        }
    }
);
```

But problem is image is not getting saved in specified folder.
How can I save downloaded image in "www/my_img/" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the value for `filePath`. This needs to be a *device-absolute-file-path* or a *filesystem URL*.

Have a look at the [comptibility notes part of the docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer#backwards-compatibility-notes):

There are some predefined folders which you can use. I think the most appropriate for your case (it's r/w, without the need to set any permissions and is persistent) is:

```
cordova.file.dataDirectory
```

You could store your downloaded image there and, when done, set the image src.

Translating this to your case:

HTML

```
<img id="downloadedimage" width="100px" height="100px">
```

JS

```
var url = 'http://myServer.com/img.jpg';
var filePath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + '/img.png';
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(url);

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    filePath,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
        document.getElementById("downloadedimage").src = entry.toURL();
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    },
    false,
    {
        headers: {
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: So `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` + `Documents` on iOS will give me folder to read/write files in it. Also "cordova.file.dataDirectory" will be same as well? is this variable directly accessible or do need to write code to get the path as mentioned by @Zappescu in his answer? which one more reliable?

Comment: I updated the answer with an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for details. In case if folder that I want to save does not exists then is it that it will be created? or first I need to create new folder under `cordova.file.dataDirectory` then save to it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should before get access to the filesystem. When ok, you can download the image in the folder you create in the dir you got access. If you need, I can give you a snippet.

EDIT:

1) access to the filesystem:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSCategory, fail);
}
```

2) if filesystem's got, get main dir:

```
function gotFSCategory(fileSystem) {
    window.fileSystem = fileSystem;
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(window.appRootDirName, {
      create : true,
      exclusive : false
    }, dirReadyCategory, fail);
}
```

3) when main dir is ready, save it and go on:

```
function dirReadyCategory(entry) {
    window.appRootDir = entry;
    console.log('application dir is ready with window.appRootDir: '+JSON.stringify(window.appRootDir));
    // Start my code:
    start_my_code();
}
```

As for the filepath var, I use this one (one for each file):

```
var filePath = window.appRootDir.toURL() + fileName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replay, how do I get access to file system. In my case directory to which I will be saving image will be existing in www folder. I just need to set path to that directory isn't it? snippet will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks for code snippet, but do I need to go through this process of method calls to get the Path or can I use `cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory` variable as mentioned by @Philip Bijker in his answer?

Comment: I didn't use the @Philip suggestion before, I can tell you that I use my code in my Android/iOS/Win apps without known issues